# I want to display my element when clicking, but my code isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the value of display to "block" when I click, I did the code but it isn't working.
I'm sorry if you find that stupid, but I can't see the mistake, please help me

HTML:

```
<img src="../icons/bell.svg" class="event-icon" id="navbell">
<div class="drop-menu" id="belldrop">  //display: none;

<script src ="common-comands.js">
    displayOnClick("navbell", "belldrop");
</script>
```

JS:

```
function displayOnClick(clickingObjId, displayObj) {
    document.getElementById(clickingObjId).onclick = function(displayObj) {
        document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Comment: A script must only have a `src` or inner content, not both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onclick function the argument displayObj is actually the event argument and you are overriding you displayObj id from your function displayOnClick.